# Filter a collection

Tags: meteor

I have a page which shows all `Stories`. I have added a filter form where you can select a `priority` and then the page should only show the stories with that priority. This is the form:

```
  <form name="filter_form">
    <select name="prio" class="form-control">
      <option value=1>High</option>
      <option value=2>Medium</option>
      <option value=3>Low</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Filter</button>
  </form>
```

This is the code to show all stories:

```
  <div class="stories">
    {{#each stories}}
      {{> storyItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
```

And this is the form handler:

```
Template.storiesList.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var prio = $(e.target).find('[name=prio]').val();
    var stories = Stories.find({prio: prio});
    return stories;
  }
});
```

I guess it isn't this easy to just do a find query and return the results, because nothing happens at the moment. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `stories` as a reactive helper. Then you can use a Session variable to link the event to the list:

```
Template.storiesList.helpers({
  'stories': function() {
    return Stories.find({prio: Session.get('prio')});
  }
});

Template.storiesList.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var prio = parseInt($(e.target).find('[name=prio]').val());
    Session.set('prio'), prio);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to use ``parseInt`` because ``prio`` is an integer to make it work.